# How do I close question that cannot be answered?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, vote-to-close

I posted a question on Stack Overflow and after that I realized that the problem (and solution) was caused by a third party and nobody could really answer the question since it wasn't possible.

How do I close such question? It degrades my accept rate.

It doesn't feel right for me to post answer to my own question and accept it, when nobody had a chance.

Here is the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267935/fileinfo-copyto-silently-fails

Comment: What about deleting?

Answer (score 9):

Just deleting it is probably easiest.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't vote to close since your rep is too low, flag it for moderator review and just leave a note explaining why you want it closed.

By the way, there is nothing wrong with posting your own answer and accepting it. You don't receive any reputation when you accept your own answer.

Comment: ...and you have to wait a couple of days after posting your answer to accept it.

Comment: I did it myself after receiving a SO Tumbleweed badge.  In fact, I delayed a little (after figuring it out myself) to make sure I got the badge.

Answer (score 1):

**Too Localized**
If the question is very localized to a specific framework/package, it really isn't that useful to a wide variety of user.

Comment: I do not see the close reason "too localized" this way, but geographically (as has been stated before).